# search and replace using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have .js file like below:

```
var LoginData=([
        {
            "PL":"ccc","browser":"firefox","execute":"n",   
        },
        {
            "PL":"aaa","browser":"firefox","execute":"n",   
        },
        {
            "PL":"bbb","browser":"firefox","execute":"n",   
        },
        {
            "PL":"ddd","browser":"firefox","execute":"n",   
    
]);
```

I need to search for string like "PL":"ccc","browser":"firefox","execute":"n"
and replace with "PL":"ccc","browser":"firefox","execute":"y".
I tried with replace command but it inserts ???????? may be because this is .js file.

Please let me know is it doable ?

Comment: Please post the PowerShell code you have so far, the results it's giving you, and the results you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

Normally something like this should work:

```psh
$filename = 'C:\path\to\your.js'

$srch = '"PL":"ccc","browser":"firefox","execute":"n"'
$repl = '"PL":"ccc","browser":"firefox","execute":"y"'

(Get-Content $filename) -replace $srch, $repl |
  Set-Content $filename -Encoding ASCII
```